# Help with stripos() and substr()

Tags: php, string

how do I remove everything before "sentido" in this string:

```
$string = "#BLitz da #PM na est do pontal sentido prainha perto do camping";
```

i want the new string to be:

```
$string = "prainha perto do camping";
```

I keep failing when I try to do it with stripos and substr, help !

Comment: what you're asking is pretty straight forward... did you *actually* tried anything?

Comment: Yes, I did and it removed everything after "sentido".

Answer (score 3):

You can accomplish it without handing any string positions:

```
$string = strstr(strstr($string, "sentido"), " ");
```

This will first search for your word, and return the remainder of the string. The second `strstr` searches for the space afterwards, and returns the rest from there.

Answer (score 0):

That's another easy way...

```
$string = "#BLitz da #PM na est do pontal sentido prainha perto do camping";

$s = explode('sentido', $string, 2);
$result = isset($s[1]) ? trim($s[1]) : "";
echo $result;
```

Output

> sentido prainha perto do camping

Comment: Make sure to use a limit so that it doesn't break when the string is included more than once.